# Need a hand using routes in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I would like to get URLs like `http://mysite.com/user/1` to route to the function `get($id) {...}` of my Controller `User`.

I have tried the following in order to do so, but I get a 404 Error, `Page Not Found` rather than the output `Hello, User 1`.

Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?!

```
//routes file
$route['user/:id'] = "user/$1";

//user controller

function get($id) {
    echo "Hi, User $id";
}
```

Edit----

My code works perfectly when I run `http://mysite.com/user/get/1`, but not when I run `http://mysite.com/user/1`.

Comment: `echo 'Hi, User $id';` should be `echo "Hi, User $id";` (double quotes instead of single quotes)

Comment: Thanks, I updated that a few seconds before you posted XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$route['user/(:num)'] = "user/get/$1";
```

More info at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$route['user/get/'] = "user/";
```

or rename get function as index function. probably no need to any changes in routes.php that way.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
['user/(:any)'] = user/get/$1;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It works perfectly if I use http://mysite.com/user/get/1, but not if I use http://mysite.com/user/1.